# Repair MapInfo Tabfile

Tags: mapinfo, tab

QGIS has a tool called *Repair Shapefile*

Does anything like that exist anywhere for MapInfo tab files?

I.e if either your .dat or .map or .id file isn't playing nice, is there a repair option specific for tab files?

Currently *v.clean* is telling me `ERROR 3: Object ID from the .ID file (404) differs from the value in the .MAP file (0).`

Both FME and MapInfo Pro are crashing when trying to do anything

Comment: Have you tried packing the table in MapInfo Pro?

Comment: Would you be able to share the file?

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller I had never heard of packing, I gave it a go and it managed to extract about half of the features but then unfortunately crashed

Comment: @BuffFox IO cannot download it, I wait 5 seconds then when clicking on the button it downloads an empty file.

Comment: @GforGIS ok that is annoying, I got an odd error from Chrome from that website, this one at least is working fine for me at the moment: https://easyupload.io/cy5inj

Comment: @BuffFox, I managed to download the data. Are the data supposed to be hexagons? I can see that I need to zoom in to get the polygons drawn.

Comment: @GforGIS correct, the reason that zooming in works is because the dodgy feature is somewhere in the north, and zooming in gets that out of the extent I believe